# Where do I learn all the CSS parameters and their actual meanings?

Tags: css

There seems to be too many attributes/parameters in CSS...
I want to know all of them and their meaning. Where can I find it?

Thanks

Comment: Really? Surely there are more CSS resources out there than neural pathways in the human brain :P

Comment: IMO the very best HTML/JavaScript/CSS resource is SelfHTML. That unfortunately won't help you, since it's German only and the English translation project has been suspended. There doesn't seem to be an international resource even half as good as SelfHTML :-/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you think that's too many try looking at something like the .NET framework. CSS is *nothing*. Still:

- http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/
- http://www.w3schools.com/css/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS
- [http://www.quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/)

Comment: W3Schools is an awful resource. Half of it is marketing for other parts of it, and half of what is left is wrong.

Comment: @David - Well I completely disagree. Sure it's advert laden, and it's far from definitive but it's still an excellent one-stop resource to have for any learner.

Comment: Agree with annakata. To get things up and running, w3schools is a viable resource.

Answer (score 5):

All in **alphabetical order** at: [CSS Property Index](http://www.eskimo.com/~bloo/indexdot/css/propindex/all.htm)
  that also gives you the access to sort by category.

By clicking on each property redirects you to a page that goes in detail of the property telling: **What it is; Allowed Values; Examples of it used**

Answer (score 4):

The specification is a good starting point: http://w3.org/TR/CSS21/

Comment: -1 The specification is NOT a good starting point; it's the worst starting point EVER. It's a great site to get fine details, but not for a beginner. Go to http://www.w3schools.com/css/ first.

Comment: W3Schools is an awful resource. Half of it is marketing for other parts of it, and half of what is left is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

its not everything, but i have this printed and hanging on my cubicle. I have to style so infrequently I can never remember the syntax.

http://lesliefranke.com/files/reference/csscheatsheet.html

Comment: Good for practical use but the poster did ask for "all of them".

Answer (score 2):

I've always found a [cheat sheet](http://lesliefranke.com/files/reference/csscheatsheet.html) to be very handy.

Answer (score 0):

There is a (yet incomplete) list of CSS properties, selectors and other components of CSS at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS_Reference and a whole bunch of resources at http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/learning

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good approach to learning CSS.  There are many attributes, but you want to focus on the ones that work consistently across browsers.  And many of the most important properties (display, position) have behaviors that depend on the values of other properties, such that learning them one-by-one will not let you understand them comprehensively.

I do recommend the book "PRO HTML and CSS Design Patterns" as a way to learn the most critical attributes and how they interact.  It does a good job on focusing on behaviors you can rely on across browsers, as well as identifying unexpected dependencies between the attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe no one mentioned devguru!

http://www.devguru.com/technologies/css2/index.asp

Answer (score 0):

[CSS Mastery](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590596145) by Andy Budd, Simon Collison, and Cameron Moll is extremely helpful as introduction to the chaotic world of CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Getting a good book is definitely a better way than looking through the specifications on W3C.

I'd also recomend [CSS Mastery](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590596145), and [Bulletproof Web Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321509021) by Dan Cederholm as great starting points.

For online resources you should have a look at the [Sitepoint CSS Reference](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css). It's also a great HTML and Javascript resource. You should also browse through the articles on [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/) and [24ways](http://24ways.org/).